# Retrieve links from divs and displaying them in another container right below the first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldn't think a better title for my question. What I am trying to do, is as follows:

**What I have:**

1. I have a series of divs with the same class name.
2. Each of these divs have a paragraph with the same class name.
3. Each paragraph an a element.
4. Below all of that, I have another series of divs with the same class name

**What I need**
I want to be able to capture the link from the first div, get what I need from that link, and display it in the second div.

I am not new to jquery, but I am not an expert nor I know all the functions just yet, how can I accomplish this?

**Script:**

```
$(function() {
var r;
var external_url;
var final_url;

  $(".a a").each(function(){

    if($(this).attr('href')=='http://www.sample.com'){

        $(".b a").each(function(){

        r = $(".b a").attr("href");

        var index_of_1 = r.indexOf("index.php?l=");

        external_url = r.substring(parseInt((index_of_1 + 1) + 5));

        var index_of_2 = external_url.indexOf("&h=");

        final_url = external_url.substring(0, index_of_2);

    }
  });

   $(".link_above").html("<a class='ext_url' href='" + decodeURIComponent(final_url) + "'>Preview</a>");
        }); 


});
```

**sample.html**

```
<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 1</a>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php?l=link1&h=3">link 1</a> example</p>
</div>
<div class="link_above"></div>
<hr />

<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 2</a>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php?l=link2&h=3">link 2</a> example</p>
</div>
<div class="link_above"></div>
<hr />

<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 3</a>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php?l=link3&h=3">link 3</a> example</p>
</div>
<div class="link_above"></div>
```

**The outcome:**

```
Site 1
This is a link 1 example

Site 2
This is a link 2 example

Site 3
This is a link 3 example
```

**What I expect**

```
Site 1
This is a link 1 example
link1

Site 2
This is a link 2 example
link2

Site 3
This is a link 3 example
link3
```

I hope I was totally clear. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you will have to change your structure a little bit, so that the div from where we are fetching the link and the div where we need to put it are both inside a div called "container" (to make it easier).

heres the structure

```
<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 1</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php?l=link1&h=3">link 1</a> example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="link_above"></div>
 </div>
<hr />

<div class="a">
 <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 2</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php?l=link1&h=4">link 1</a> example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="link_above"></div>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="a">
  <a href="http://www.sample.com">Site 3</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p class="b">This is a <a href="http://www.web.com/index.php? l=link1&h=5">link 1</a> example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="link_above"></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery like this

```
$(function() {
   var i = 1;
   $(".link_above").each(function(){
    var link = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href')
    $(this).html("<a href='"+link+"'>link"+i+"</a>")
    i++;
   })
});
```

heres the fiddel [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc94vsyd/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code works perfect. The problem is that the html code is retrieved from an external server, so I have no control over the HTML part of it.

Comment: I guess I can add the div container with jquery.

Comment: lemme see if i can come up the solution with the same structure. ill post it if i get one

Comment: @ilovecerveza try this  `var link = $(this).prev().find('a').attr('href')` , if you cannot change the structure. But be sure you have the same structure return from the server every time. :)   [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pc94vsyd/3/)